# Remember me functionality and Token in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am looking for a better approach to my problem here. I have a remember me functionality on my login form. Ones the user click on remember me box, My API sends me Token.

My question is what is the best way to store this token and authenticate user again when they are back to my site?

What I thought,

1. Create a Cookie and store token there.
2. Create a local Storage.

Please give me any advice which might help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use document.cookie with a factory code like this:

Creates a cookie (for example this one expires in a year):

```
app.factory('$remember', function() {
    return function(name, values) {
        var cookie = name + '=';

        cookie += values + ';';

        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 365);

        cookie += 'expires=' + date.toString() + ';';

        document.cookie = cookie;
    }
});
```

This factory removes the cookie:

```
app.factory('$forget', function() {
    return function(name) {
        var cookie = name + '=;';
        cookie += 'expires=' + (new Date()).toString() + ';';

        document.cookie = cookie;
    }
});
```

Then whenever a user successfully logs in cache the key using $remember:

```
$remember('my_cookie_name', response.user._id);
```

And always check if the cookie is there when logging in the user else use a a standard login and save it to their cookies. If the remember me is not enabled, forget the document.cookie

Comment: nice answer :) I will try and let you know.

Comment: Can you please explain more on how to check if my cookie is set? Currently I am using a Boolean flag but does not work. Any idea?

Comment: cookie is not removing from browser even after it is expired.

Comment: @willjleong how we check cookie ? and then apply condition according to cookie. can you further explain .

Answer (score 15):

**Use ngCookies:**
The ngCookies module provides a convenient wrapper for reading and writing browser cookies.

First you install ngCookies in your app using bower `bower install angular-cookies@X.Y.Z` or manully.

then inject `ngCookies` in your app like
 `angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);`

then simply use like

```
angular.module('App', ['ngCookies'])
      .controller('demo', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
          // Setting a cookie
          $cookies.put('cookieName', 'object');
          // Retrieving a cookie
          var sample= $cookies.get('cookieName');
         // Remove a cookie
          $cookies.remove('cookieName');
      }]);
```

Comment: This should be used as an accepted answer as it is not a good practice to use DOM objects inside angular code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Token Authentication/ Restful API then the preferred way is to use the `localStorage`. However using this approach unless the user selects to "Remember Me", they'll be required to login again to each browser tab they open. Because each item saved with `sessionStorage` is only available to a single tab.
I created a library to simplify this and synchronize session data across all opened tabs. The user experience is similar to that offered by cookie authentication.
With this you do something like:

```
if (rememberMe)
    storageManager.savePermanentData('data', 'key');
else
    storageManager.saveSyncedSessionData('data', 'key');
```

And you retrieve data by `var myData = storageManager.getData('key');`

You can download this library from this link: http://www.ebenmonney.com/blog/how-to-implement-remember-me-functionality-using-token-based-authentication-and-localstorage-in-a-web-application

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app', ['ngCookies'])
  .controller('mainController', ['$cookies', '$timeout', function($cookies, $timeout) {
    
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.message = '';
    
    vm.getCookies = getCookies;
    vm.setCookies = setCookies;
    vm.clearCookies = clearCookies;
    
    getCookies();
    
    function getCookies()
    {
      vm.var1 = $cookies.get('var1');
      vm.var2 = $cookies.get('var2');
    }
    
    function setCookies()
    {
      $cookies.put('var1', vm.var1);
      $cookies.put('var2', vm.var2);
      
      if (vm.var1 && vm.var2)
        showMessage('Cookies set successefully!');
      else
        showMessage('Please enter some value.');
    }
    
    function clearCookies()
    {
      $cookies.remove('var1');
      $cookies.remove('var2');
      
      getCookies();
      
      showMessage('Cookies cleared successefully!');
    }
    
    function showMessage(msg)
    {
      vm.message = msg;
      $timeout(function() {
        vm.message = '';
      }, 2000);
    }
    
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```css
body
{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">

  <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a href="https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies">ngCookies</a> sample 
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
      
      Enter some value, press 'Set cookies', than refresh page. (Refresh button on right top corner)
      <hr>

      <form ng-submit="ctrl.setCookies()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="var1">Cookies for VAR1</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="var1" placeholder="value" ng-model="ctrl.var1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="var2">Cookies for VAR1</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="var2" placeholder="value" ng-model="ctrl.var2">
        </div>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="ctrl.clearCookies()">Clear</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Set cookies</button>
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" ng-show="ctrl.message">
    {{ctrl.message}}
  </div>
</div>
```