# how to remember a user?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a view with user login and password.

```
    <form action="submitLogin()">
  <label class="item item-input">
     <span class="input-label">Username</span>
     <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.username">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
       <span class="input-label">Password</span>
      <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password">
      </label>
      <p style="text-align:center"ng-hide=myflag>wrong credentials</P>
       <label class="item">
       <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
   </label>
   </form>
```

what i need is i need to put a remember checkbox and i need controller for it to work. when user tick remember me.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645271/remember-me-functionality-and-token-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use `ngStorage`. You can save user information or token.
To install just type:

```
bower install ngstorage
```

or

```
npm install ngstorage
```

Usage:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngStorage'])
.controller('Ctrl', function($localStorage){
    ...
});
```

For more information visit: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage