# Remember Password option in angularjs

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I have a sample angularjs login page, now I want to add functionality to my script for remembering password.

```
 <body ng-app="app" >
<div class="main">
    <div class="login-form">
        <h1>Login</h1>           
        <form ng-submit=submit()>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="USERNAME" ng-model="person.firstName" required />
            <span class="error" ng-show="mainForm.usernamename.$error.required">required</span>
            <input type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Password" ng-model="person.pswd" required />
            <span class="error" ng-show="mainForm.pswd.$error.required">required</span>
           <label>
                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="remember" data-ng-click="rememberMe()">   Remember Me
                    </label>
            <div class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
            </div>
            <p><a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>   
</div>
```

```
<script>
  angular.module('app', [])

  var LoginCtrl= function ($scope) {

  $scope.submit = function () {          

      //return false;
  } };
```

Here is a demo too `plunker`:https://plnkr.co/edit/4WoGzXnzUfkBqzeFrTW9?p=preview

Will be thankful if anyone can provide code for this!!

Comment: you could save the generated hash, which is a repesentation of the password in the localstorage or the cookies

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586938/remember-password-with-angularjs-and-ng-submit

Comment: @Tobias Timm: Iam not sure of how to do that.. Could you pls provide code for a better understanding

Comment: @user 013948: I require a checkbox and not autocomplete option. User should have a choice whether to make the password remembered or not.

Comment: you can refer the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645271/remember-me-functionality-and-token-in-angularjs

Comment: you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645271/remember-me-functionality-and-token-in-angularjs

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the code.  While external links/demos might be helpful, they are no substitute for code in the post.

Comment: Code in your post is mandatory.  The plunker link is optional but very helpful.  Please copy the relevant code into your post from your plunker.

Answer (score 0):

```
I would use document.cookie with a factory code like this:

Creates a cookie (for example this one expires in a year):

app.factory('$remember', function() {
    return function(name, values) {
        var cookie = name + '=';
        cookie += values + ';';
    enter code here
        var date = new Date();date.setDate(date.getDate() + 365);cookie += 'expires=' + date.toString() + ';';
        document.cookie = cookie;
    }
});
This factory removes the cookie:

app.factory('$forget', function() {
    return function(name) {
        var cookie = name + '=;';
        cookie += 'expires=' + (new Date()).toString() + ';';
        document.cookie = cookie;
    }
});

$remember('my_cookie_name', response.user._id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, but I want to know how to use the above in my code

Comment: check for submit event in your js file where you have written the code for the submit(inside your controller) and your login credential ok that time you have to set this parameter, if you want full code access then mail me i will work and send the whole code for you

Comment: you should avoid to use $ for self-coded services/factories, because you can occur collisions with built-in factories and services that use the $ prefix.